# Dividing N items in p groups

Tags: algorithm

You are given **N** total number of item, **P** group in which you have to divide the N items.

Condition is the product of number of item held by each group should be max.

example **N=10 and P=3** you can divide the 10 item in **{3,4,3}** since **3x3x4=36** max possible product.

Comment: ?? N/P (with adjusting for rounding) will *always* yield the largest possible numbers, and thus the largest product. No?

Comment: N=20 and P =5 in this case {4,4,4,4,4} is result 1024 is the max product possible

Comment: @YS Are you asking or stating the result for N = 20 or P = 5? The partition that you give is indeed optimal according to your objective function. Are you looking for a proof of optimality?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to form `P` groups of roughly `N / P` elements. However, this will not always be possible, as `N` might not be divisible by `P`, as is the case for your example.

So form groups of `floor(N / P)` elements initially. For your example, you'd form:

```
floor(10 / 3) = 3
=> groups = {3, 3, 3}
```

Now, take the remainder of the division of `N` by `P`:

```
10 mod 3 = 1
```

This means you have to distribute 1 more item to your groups (you can have up to `P - 1` items left to distribute in general):

```
for i = 0 up to (N mod P) - 1:
  groups[i]++

=> groups = {4, 3, 3} for your example
```

Which is also a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

For fun I worked out a proof of the fact that it in an optimal solution either all numbers = N/P or the numbers are some combination of floor(N/P) and ceiling(N/P). The proof is somewhat long, but proving optimality in a discrete context is seldom trivial. I would be interested if anybody can shorten the proof.

Lemma: For P = 2 the optimal way to divide N is into {N/2, N/2} if N is even and {floor(N/2), ceiling(N/2)} if N is odd.

This follows since the constraint that the two numbers sum to N means that the two numbers are of the form x, N-x.

The resulting product is (N-x)x = Nx - x^2. This is a parabola that opens down. Its max is at its vertex at x = N/2. If N is even this max is an integer. If N is odd, then x = N/2 is a fraction, but such parabolas are strictly unimodal, so the closer x gets to N/2 the larger the product. x = floor(N/2) (or ceiling, it doesn't matter by symmetry) is the closest an integer can get to N/2, hence {floor(N/2),ceiling(N/2)} is optimal for integers.

General case: First of all, a global max exists since there are only finitely many integer partitions and a finite list of numbers always has a max. Suppose that {x_1, x_2, ..., x_P} is globally optimal. Claim: given and i,j we have

|x_i - x_ j| <= 1

In other words: any two numbers in an optimal solution differ by at most 1. This follows immediately from the P = 2 lemma (applied to N = x_i + x_ j).

From this claim it follows that there are at most two distinct numbers among the x_i. If there is only 1 number, that number is clearly N/P. If there are two numbers, they are of the form a and a+1. Let k = the number of x_i which equal a+1, hence P-k of the x_i = a. Hence

(P-k)a + k(a+1) = N, where k is an integer with 1 <= k < P

But simple algebra yields that a = (N-k)/P = N/P - k/P.

Hence -- a is an integer < N/P which differs from N/P by less than 1 (k/P < 1)
Thus a = floor(N/P) and a+1 = ceiling(N/P).

QED